# Random of Table Header Name of another table via INDEX MATCH

Tags: excel, random, indexing, excel-formula, excel-tables

I have these 2 tables:
[image]

On column B i'm trying to get one of the Header Names of a feature that is not empty on Table B. I want it to be selected **randomly**. The order of the items in Table A can be different than the order of the items in Table B, I'll need some sort of INDEX MATCH here too.

Excel Version: Office 365

Attempted Formula: I tried to base my formula on this:

```
=INDEX(datarange,RANDBETWEEN(1,COLUMNS(datarange)),1)
```

but there are more things to consider, like header name if the index match of the same fruit isn't empty, so I know it is more complex.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I've edited my original question with my Excel version and attempted formula. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have access to dynamic arrays you could try:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=LET(X,FILTER(E$1:I$1,INDEX(E$2:I$6,MATCH(A2,D$2:D$6,0),0)<>"","No Feature"),INDEX(X,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(X))))
```

Or without `LET()`:

```
=@SORT(SORT(CHOOSE({1;2;3},E$1:I$1,FILTER(E$2:I$6,D$2:D$6=A2),RANDARRAY(1,5)),3,1,1),2,-1,1)
```

If you are working through actual tables this should spill down results under `Random Feature` automatically. However, if one does not use tables, you could nest the above in `BYROW()` if you are an 365-insider:

```
=BYROW(A2:A6,LAMBDA(r,LET(X,FILTER(E$1:I$1,INDEX(E$2:I$6,MATCH(r,D$2:D$6,0),0)<>"","No Feature"),INDEX(X,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(X))))))
```

This would not work with the 2nd option where we used '@' to parse only the topleft value of our array (implicit intersection).

---

The idea is that:

- A combination of `INDEX()` & `MATCH()` will 'slice' the row of interest out of the lookup-table based on our input.
- In the 2nd step we'd use `FILTER()` to only leave those headers where the elements from the herefor returned array are not *empty*. In the case all elements are empty, this function will return the value "No Feature" as a headsup for the users.
- In our final step we combine `INDEX()` with `RANDBETWEEN()`. The latter will return a random integer between a LBound (1 in our case) and an Ubound which we based on the amount of returned elements.

I tried to visualize this below.

---

[image]

Comment: These are actual tables. defined as "Table_A" & "Table_B". how will I change the formula please to these tables? thank you so much!

Comment: @JvDV, You beat me to it! It's nice to see all the new formulas available to insiders.

Comment: @Kobe2424, change the range-references into the table-references. Just select them and drag a new table-reference.

Comment: amazing. thank you guys, both answers helped me, I don't know which to mark as the correct answer. I have another question regarding random value, much easier I believe, should I post it to you guys or open a new thread?

Comment: New questions get new posts, but since you believe it's an easy one; make sure you research for the answer first since any new post should include what you have tried and what you need help with. As to which answer to accept is up to you. It does not matter. You can however vote up all answers that were helpfull to you @Kobe2424

Comment: I'll check now if nothing comes up I will create a new post. I'll also random between you guys who's get the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have Excel 365 and a volatile result is acceptable:

```
=LET(
    Fruits, Table_B[Fruit],
    Properties, Table_B[[Red]:[Green]],
    PropertiesHeaders, Table_B[[#Headers],[Red]:[Green]],
    ThisFruit, [@Fruits],

    ThisProperties, FILTER(Properties, Fruits = ThisFruit),
    ThisPropertiesFiltered, FILTER(PropertiesHeaders, ThisProperties <> 0),
    ThisPropertiesCount, COUNTA(ThisPropertiesFiltered),
    IndexRand, RANDBETWEEN(1,ThisPropertiesCount),
    IFERROR(INDEX(ThisPropertiesFiltered,IndexRand),"-")
)
```

`ThisProperties` is the row in `Table_B` for your fruit. I left out the column for the fruit names.

`ThisPropertiesFiltered` is the names of the properties that the fruit has. I filtered the header names based on if the fruit row had a non-zero value or not.

`IndexRand` gets a random number between 1 and the number of available properties. Note, if there are zero available properties, `ThisPropertiesFiltered` returns `#CALC!` so `ThisPropertiesCount` will return 1. This is handled later on.

Last we use `INDEX` to get the random property name. `IFERROR` returns "-" if no properties were available.

Here are the tables:

Table_A:

| Fruits | Result |
| --- | --- |
| Watermelon | Heavy |
| Melon | Green |
| Banana | Tropic |
| Peach | Red |
| Apple | Green |

Table_B:

| Fruit | Red | Yellow | Tropic | Heavy | Green |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | x |  |  |  | x |
| Banana |  | x | x |  |  |
| Peach | x |  |  |  |  |
| Melon |  |  |  |  | x |
| Watermelon | x |  |  | x |  |

Comment: amazing. thank you guys, both answers helped me, I don't know which to mark as the correct answer. I have another question regarding random value, much easier I believe, should I post it to you guys or open a new thread?